# HAProxy: drops connections from DBCP, why?

Tags: mysql, timeout, connection-pooling, load-testing, haproxy

I have a webapp (Tomcat/Hibernate/DBCP 1.4) that runs queries against MySQL, and this works fine for a certain load, say 50 queries a second. When I route the same moderate load through HAProxy (still just using a single database), I get a failure, maybe one for every 500 queries. My app reports:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 196,898 milliseconds ago.    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor210.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3567)
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3017)
...
```

Meanwhile the HAProxy log is showing a lot of entries like:

```
27] mysql mysql/db03 0/0/34605 2364382 cD 3/3/3/3/0 0/0
Oct 15 15:43:12 localhost haproxy[3141]: 127.0.0.1:35500 [15/Oct/2012:15:42:50.0
```

The "cD" apparently indicates a state of client timeout. So whereas my webapp is saying that HAProxy is refusing to accepting new connections, HAProxy is saying that my webapp is not accepting data back.

I am not including my HAProxy configuration, because I've tried many different parameter values, with essentially the same result. In particular, I've set maxconn to both high and low values, in both global and server sections, and what always happens in the stats is that the max sessions rises to no more than about 7. My JDBC pool size is also high.

Is it generally ok to use a JDBC pool and a HAProxy pool together? Have people run into this kind of problem before?

I have an idea on how to solve this, which is to send a "validation query" before every query. But there's a certain overhead there, and I'd still like to know why my webapp succeeds when it goes straight to MySQL, but gets dropped connections on going through HAProxy.

How can I debug further and get more information than just "cD"? I tried running HAProxy in debug mode, but it doesn't seem to reveal anything more.

Comment: I do have similar problems. you mentioned below that you "moved on"... Can you tell me what you did to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tune.bufsize 20480
tune.maxrewrite 2048
```

See [the ha-docs](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt) for their meaning.  You have to do this with all eyes on it as you're entering the grey zone of potential lethal params.  But it's worth a try to see if this works.  I just solved a problem that made no sense vs. the documentation with this.

The defaults are 16k vs 1k.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I don't know if this is the correct solution, as I moved on before I got your answer.

Comment: You could always show your appreciation and bump it up.   No need to accept something that can't be verified.

Comment: @JamesMcCabe you say you moved on... because you found a solution?

Comment: A little old, but you could have shared the solution for reference.